# OTG mode Multi (g_multi) is not working on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: usb, ethernet, storage, otg

I want to use the Raspberry Pi 4 as ethernet and mass storage device. According to the documentation I have to do configure the following files:

```
/boot/config.txt:
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral

/boot/cmdline.txt:
modules-load=dwc2,g_multi

/etc/modprobe.d/g_multi.conf:
options g_multi file=/myfile.bin host_addr=11:22:33:44:55:66 dev_addr=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

Now when I connect the Raspberry Pi to my Windows computer the mass storage works and there is also a serial port (that I don't need). Unfortunately I can't ping the raspberry pi and the device is not listed as USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget in the device manager.

When I use the g_ether OTG mode, the device is listed as USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget and I can ping the device. But I also need the mass storage function.

Comment: have you read the replies on your post [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=283168)

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a windows driver problem.